# Class 'Facebook' not found

Tags: php, facebook

Right. This is starting to do my nogging damage. I feel like this should be super simple but I cannot seem to get it to work.

For some reason I am getting:

> Class 'Facebook' not found

Here is my folder structure:

```
|admin/
|---sdks/
|----facebook/
|-----5.5.0/
|------src/
|-------Facebook/
|--------Facebook.php
|       /// rest of files
|facebook_test.php
```

inside **facebook_test.php:**

```
//include the Facebook PHP SDK
include_once '/sdks/facebook/5.5.0/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
include_once '/sdks/facebook/5.5.0/src/Facebook/Facebook.php';


//instantiate the Facebook library with the APP ID and APP SECRET
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => '123456789',
  'secret' => 'a123456789b',
  'cookie' => true
));
```

I have tried:

1) Getting the raw Facebook.php file as suggested here: [PHP Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172944/php-fatal-error-class-facebook-not-found-in)

2) requiring the autoload as suggested here: ['Class 'Facebook\Facebook' not found" Facebook SDK error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366714/class-facebook-facebook-not-found-facebook-sdk-error)

However these have no effect.

I am using version **5.5.0** of the SDK.

Alos, I have chedked **Facebook.php** it does contain the class Facebook

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook SDK uses [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) so:

```
new \Facebook\Facebook(..)
```

you should just check manual, it's literally in every single example as well in link you provided ...

---

This is all you need to do

```
<?php

include 'src/Facebook/autoload.php'; // path to your autoload.php
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook(...);
```

Comment: Not me. Ok, I knew it was something simple. Would you be able to show me what I would need to put into my code to make it work? The above example seems to fail. I am a noob (sigh)

Comment: @JamesG i edited my answer, just include autoload and create class

Answer (score 1):

According to [Facebook Documentation](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk), it uses namespace in v5.x. So, you should change your code like this:

```
//include the Facebook PHP SDK
require( __DIR__.'/sdks/facebook/5.5.0/src/Facebook/autoload.php');

// load namespaces
use Facebook\Facebook;

//instantiate the Facebook library with the APP ID and APP SECRET
$facebook = new \Facebook\Facebook(array(
  'appId' => '123456789',
  'secret' => 'a123456789b',
  'cookie' => true
));
```